# How to upload data from arduino to a free server

Tags: android, parse-platform, arduino, temboo

I have arduino mega 2560, and ESP8266 Serial WIFI Wireless.

I want to upload data from the arduino to a server. do I need anything else but the ESP8266? (like GSM / ethernet ..?).

and I need to upload this data to a free server, is parse.com good for me? because it has a SDK for arduino YUN only... what about temboo.com ?

and then I want to read this data from an android app. and the same on the opposite way... (from android => to server => to arduino).

where can I start reading about this?

Comment: "do I need anything else but the ESP8266?" - Of course you will need a WiFi access point/router connected to the internet. If you need to be mobile, either a GSM module or a cellphone with WiFi hotspot feature would be a good start.

Comment: Thank you. Of course I have a WiFi access... I am asking about (Hardware) items for the arduino...

Comment: Then, obviously, you won't need "GSM / ethernet"... and no other hardware.

Comment: parse.com is RESTful, isn't it? Fortunately, the ESP will do the tedious TCP/IP handling for you. So if you can get a library for REST, or one for HTTP and one for JSON, you should be on a good way.

Comment: well am newde to this and I dont know why I need and from where I will get thees librarys.. (any links for reading about the needy of this?)
pasre is RESTful for the YUN arduino.. dunno if it will be good for mega2560.